# UWP SteamSocketListener A wildcard address cannot be used with a specific port when the Wake standby action is set

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp, background-task

I'm trying to run a StreamSocketListener in a background task of a UWP app.

I followed below MS example and my EnableTransferOwnership call is exactly same as MS example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background#socket-broker-and-the-socketactivitytrigger

[image: MS Sample Code]

However I receive an exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll WinRT information: A wildcard address
> cannot be used with a specific port when the Wake standby action is
> set.  Try using BindEndpointAsync with a non-null localHostName.
> Service name bind exeception: A method was called at an unexpected
> time.

My question is why it cause this exception?

Could MS example source be wrong?

```
public async Task<bool> SocketInitListener(string socketPort, IBackgroundTaskRegistration backgroundRegistrationTask)
{
    SocketPort = socketPort;
    SocketLstener = new StreamSocketListener();
    SocketLstener.EnableTransferOwnership(backgroundRegistrationTask.TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.Wake);
    SocketLstener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnection;
    SocketLstener.Control.KeepAlive = false;
    try
    {
        await SocketLstener.BindServiceNameAsync(SocketPort);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Service name bind exeception: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also my app need to listen to this specific port and it does not know about client HostName.

So I don't think I can use BindEndpointAsync() in my case.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried the official sample - [SocketActivityStreamSocket](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket) to see it will show the same error?

Comment: Thanks for sopping by, Actually I checked the sample source.
But that sample is for StreamSocket (not SteamSocketListener) and
it use SteamSocket.ConnectAsync() instead of StreamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync()

Sample source build find, but that does not answer my specific situation.

Comment: When did you call `SocketInitListener` method? Are you calling it in the background task?

Comment: Hi Roy Thanks again,
I call SocketInitListener() method at application startup (In my App.xaml.cs inside App() method).
It is during that sequence I get this exception.

Comment: Do you have other service port to test? I want to know if this behavior happens to every port you are using.

Comment: Actually Yes, I tested with these ports { "51000", "49155", "49200", "50500", "50505", "51100", "51511", "51515", "52000", "55555" }. I my implementation, server try to BindServiceNameAsync() in above order until a success port is found.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] about this.

Comment: Could you please share a repro about this?