# UWP In-Process background task does not trigger from SocketActivityTrigger

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp, triggers, background-task

My app need to use socket communication when app is suspended.

I tried with out of process background task without a success.

[UWP SteamSocketListener A wildcard address cannot be used with a specific port when the Wake standby action is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75457335/uwp-steamsocketlistener-a-wildcard-address-cannot-be-used-with-a-specific-port-w?noredirect=1#comment133220298_75457335)

I'm evaluating other options and trying to use in-process background task for this.

But it seems like default OnBackgroundActivated() method does not get called from SocketActivityTrigger() event.

This is what I have done up to now.

1. Register background task in App.xaml.cs public App() method

```cs
foreach (var current in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{
    if (current.Value.Name == "SocketBackgroundTask")
    {
        _backgroundRegistrationTask = current.Value;
        break;
    }
}

if (_backgroundRegistrationTask == null)
{
    var socketBackgroundTask = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    socketBackgroundTask.Name = "SocketBackgroundTask";
    socketBackgroundTask.SetTrigger(new SocketActivityTrigger());
    var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    try
    {
        _backgroundRegistrationTask = socketBackgroundTask.Register();
        if (_backgroundRegistrationTask != null)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("BackgroundTaskRegistration OK :" + result.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("BackgroundTaskRegistration NG! :" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

2. I have my OnBackgroundActivated() method like this

   ```cs
   base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
   IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance = args.TaskInstance;
   SocketActivityTriggerDetails socketTriggerDetails = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SocketActivityTriggerDetails;

   if (socketTriggerDetails != null)
   {
       var socketInformation = socketTriggerDetails.SocketInformation;
       Trace.WriteLine("Socket Information = " + socketInformation.ToString());
       Trace.WriteLine("Trigger Reason = " + socketTriggerDetails.Reason.ToString());
       _socketActivityTask = new SocketActivityTask();
       _socketActivityTask.Run(taskInstance);
   }
   ```
3. This should work according to MS [Create and register an in-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task)

   Only change I did was changing the trigger to SocketActivityTrigger. But it is not working.

   When I checked the event viewer, I see error **The background task with entry point Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.DefaultInProcBackgroundTask and name SocketBackgroundTask failed to activate with error code 0x8027025B.** even though background task Register() method call is a success.
   [image: The background task with entry point Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.DefaultInProcBackgroundTask and name SocketBackgroundTask failed to activate with error code 0x8027025B.]

I could not find any resource/sample source about SocketActivityTrigger being used in in-process background task. Appreciate if somebody can share any insights or point me somewhare.

Comment: I checked the error code 0x8027025B, it seems that your application is closed. Error code 0x8027025B: **E_APPLICATION_ACTIVATION_EXEC_FAILURE The app didn't start.** [In-process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#in-process-and-out-of-process-background-tasks) closed after the app is closed. Out-of-process background task still runs after the app is closed, because it run in separate processes.

Comment: What capabilities are you using in the application? Are you testing plugged in the outlet or battery? You have already taken a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/netWorking/NetWork-communications-in-the-background

Comment: @Dileepa Rathnayake, have you tried Out-of-process background task?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Actually yes, I tried Out-of-process background task also. But I had an issue there as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75457335/uwp-steamsocketlistener-a-wildcard-address-cannot-be-used-with-a-specific-port-w?noredirect=1#comment133592661_75457335
Unfortunately did not have time to create a MRE repo for both cases yet.
Currently I'm working on a patch using ExtendedExecutionSession (so that app will not suspend after minimizing) will update the result later.